# Why cur.fetchone show as None when fetch a data?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code. I have a problem with fetching the data from a database. I'm calling to a function `select_db_test` to get the information from the database. I'm using the variable `program_id` to get the id that I stored in the list so I can use them to search for the data in the same row as the id in a database.

When I try this:

```
def select_db_test(self):
    database_path = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://database/tvguide', 'source.db'))

    if os.path.exists(database_path):
        conn = database.connect(database_path)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        nextprogram_id = ''.join(str(x) for x in self.nextprogram_id)
        program_id = int(nextprogram_id)
        cur.execute('SELECT stop_date FROM programs where button_id=?', [program_id])
        stop_date = cur.fetchone()
        print "stop_date"
        print stop_date
```

It will connect to a database, but the data will return as `None`.

I don't really understand where the problem is coming from. I am sure that I have not missing something.

Do you know why the data return as None and how I can fix the problem?

Comment: Is it possible to try running your exact select statement in the database?

Comment: yeah sure why not?

Comment: What happens when you do that?

Comment: the `stop_data` show as `None`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It is probably because 1. Your select statement is incorrect or there is nothing matching your query in the datatbase.

Comment: i have got the select statement correct because I have matching the database column names and i have also matching with the `program_id` data in the variable to get the data I want to fetch from the database. I keep getting the `None` as the return data. I can't figure it out as I have tried everything and I can't find out what is wrong. Can you help?

Comment: Any idea?????????????????????